# HTTP Request in FOR loop is not executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I have a script that is meant to execute a number of HTTP requests and then store the data retrieved:

```
var ParseXbrl = require('parse-xbrl')
var request = require('request');
var tickers = ['AAPL','F','TSLA','GOOG','MSFT'];

var json = "";
var XML = "";
var Data = [];

for(z in tickers){
request
.get('https://www.valuespreadsheet.com/iedgar/results.php?stock=' + tickers[z] + '&output=json')
.on('response', function(response) {
   response.on('data', function(chunk){
       json += chunk;
   });
   response.on('end',function(){
       json = JSON.parse(json);

       request
           .get(json.filings[2].instanceUrl)
           .on('response', function(response) {
               response.on('data', function(chunk){
                   XML  += chunk;
               });
               response.on('end',function() {
                   ParseXbrl.parseStr(XML).then(function(parsedDoc) {
                     console.log(parsedDoc);
                    var x = 0;
                       for(i in parsedDoc){
                            Data[tickers[z]][x]=parsedDoc[i];
                            x++
                            console.log(Data);
                       }
                   });
               });
               });
             });
   });
 }
```

The above script returns the following error code:

```
undefined:1
[object Object]{
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (Test.js:18:24)
    at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1047:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
[Finished in 0.871s]
```

However when I change the array `tickers` such that it contains only one value e.g. `tickers = ['AAPL']` the code works (what ticker I use is irrelevant).

I did some testing and noticed that when I added `console.log(z);` to my code it logged both `0` and `1` before it attempted to retrieve any data. This leads me to suspect that my code is looping through `for(z in tickers)` before it executes a `request`

Comment: It's been a while since I've done much Node. Is `json` you're passing into `JSON.parse` a string, or is it still a buffer?

Comment: I am pretty sure it's a string, I did `console.log(json);` and it returned a string. That might be an entirely wrong way to check it and if so, what is the best way I can check to see if it is a buffer vs a string?

Comment: Nevermind, adding a buffer to a string results in a string. But your `json` string is declared outside of the `for` loop, so the results of each of your requests would be appended to the same string. What if you tried moving your `var json = "";` into the response callback? Regardless of whether or not that's the problem, it's a good idea to have your variables be as local as they can be.

Comment: I am afraid that did not work, thank you never the less.

Comment: because asynchronous code ... by the time Data[tickers[z]][x]=parsedDoc[i]; is reached, your z will always be the last index. in fact, I can't see how that code would work for even one ticker ... seeing as you assign to `Data[tickers[z]][x]` but `Data[tickers[z]]` would be `undefined` -

Comment: just leaving it here as food for thought - promises make asynchronous code easier to work with - [your code using promises everywhere, not just ParseXrbl](https://jsfiddle.net/jjc6me2L/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON string you are building is going to be invalid after the first request. If the API is returning an object, you are going to end up with:

```
"{ response1: 'foo'}{ response2: 'bar}{ etc }"
```

Which `JSON.parse` will error on, since it is not a single object (and that's what `JSON.parse` expects). If it's an array you have a similar problem:

```
"[responseArray1][responseArray2]"
```

Again, that will not parse because `JSON.parse` expects a single object. Brett is correct in his comment, you need to move where your `json` variable is defined:

```
.on('response', function(response) {
   var json = "";
   response.on('data', function(chunk){
       json += chunk;
   });
```

That way you won't be concatenating multiple request responses.

The same also applies for `XML = '';`